# overlapping skeletons of images

Tags: opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, scikit-image, medial-axis

I did `sketalization` of images using morphology module of `skimage`.
The output seems quite cool but I want the output to somehow be over my threshold/binary output so that I can confirm whether the output is accurate or not. I tried achieving this using PIL but in vain.

Answer (score 1):

To keep things simple make a copy of the original image

```
result = img.copy()
```

Outline the skeleton as follows:

```
result[skeleton == 255] = (255,255,255)
```

Displaying `result` should give the expected output

**UPDATE:**

I have provided complete solution using OpenCV:

```
img = cv2.imread('object.jpg')

# convert to grayscale
g = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# inverse binary image
th = cv2.threshold(g,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# obtain skeleton
sk = cv2.ximgproc.thinning(th, None, 1)
```

[image]

```
# create copy of original image and superimpose the skeleton
result = img.copy()
result[sk == 255] = (255,255,255)
```

[image]

Result for an additional image shared recently:

[image]

**Problems:**

There are some problem as to why it doesn't work with your code:

1. Your `img` is read as grayscale. The snippet `result[sk == 255] = (255,255,255)` expectes `result` to be 3-channel RGB/BGR image hence you face the value error.
2. Another thing I noted is, using `imread` from `skimage` reads the image in `float` data type with pixel range 0 to 1.0. Later when you use `skeleton = medial_axis(canny).astype(np.uint8)` converts `skeleton` to `int` data type but also restricts pixel range from 0 to 1. As a result, even the portion expected to be in white is seen in black

Comment: `result = img.copy()
    result[skeleton == 255] = (255, 255, 255)
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(result, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    plt.show()`

Comment: im getting this error->. `--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError Traceback (most recent call last) /tmp/ipykernel_33/3508954884.py in <module> 29 30 result = img.copy() ---> 31 result[skeleton == 255] = (255,255,255) 32 plt.imshow((result)) 33 plt.show() ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 3 input values to the 0 output values where the mask is true `

Comment: an update i change the code to -> `result = img.copy()
    result[skeleton==255] = (225,)` the output image does not show the skeleton over it T_T

Comment: and on doing `result = img.copy()
    result[skeleton==0] = (255,)` only skeleton apppears T_T

Comment: Thank you so very much Jeru. You've helped a lot   _ / \ _